# Getting Authorization code of my google drive account in android

Tags: authorization, access-token, google-drive-android-api

I am building an application using the reference [Google Developer Sample Project](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java). According to this tutorial i will get an authorization code from browser and will put it later in my application.But i don't want to work like this. I need to get the authorization code in direct way. Actually I want to upload file to the Google Drive account with a button click event. Every thing should be done hidden inside button click event.

Comment: You saw you are doing Android development, but the quickstart you linked to is for the standard Java API.  Any reason you aren't using the Android-specific version? https://developers.google.com/drive/android/  This will use Android-style authorization.

Comment: @CherylSimon thanks for your comment, actually i was expecting that it will work in android too, as android use the same language (JAVA).
can i use the code in android?

Comment: @CherylSimon Now i am using the android tutorial of google drive serives, which you refer me, but i have one problem there